# Writing binary data to registry using Inno Setup Pascal Scripting

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need your help again please. I want write in registry with a hex entry. How can we do this? I need a function under `[Code]` section.

This is what I do:

```pascal
procedure ADDRegistry;
begin
  RegWriteDWordValue(HKLM64,'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FIDTPU\Parameters', 'CalibMode', 0);

  RegWriteBinaryValue(HKLM64,'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FIDTPU\Parameters', 'Caldata9' + 
    #7c#17#17#01#26#08#1f#0f#50#02#cf#08#40#0f#f7#13#f6#01#26#1f#f7#01#6b#27#e7#1d#81#15#54#00#27#df#2d#06#dd#2b#e2#1d#61#17#56#00#18#9f#af#01#df#2b#bd#1d#49#19#b3#01#0d#bf#3b#03#87#2d#c6#1d#c9#10#cc#03#19#7f#7d#01#d9#2d#ae#1d#f9#13#54#00#34#5f#03#02#6b#2e#aa#1d#6f#14#54#00#30#9f#55#00#6b#2e#9c#1d#65#17#e5#02#34#df#b3#01#e9#2f#99#1d);
end;
```

The `RegWriteDWordValue` works, but the `RegWriteBinaryValue` does not.

The original registry entry with hex is:

> "Caldata9"=hex:7c,17,17,01,26,08,1f,0f,50,02,cf,08,40,0f,f7,13,f6,01,26,1f,f7,
> 01,6b,27,e7,1d,81,15,54,00,27,df,2d,06,dd,2b,e2,1d,61,17,56,00,18,9f,af,01,
> df,2b,bd,1d,49,19,b3,01,0d,bf,3b,03,87,2d,c6,1d,c9,10,cc,03,19,7f,7d,01,d9,
> 2d,ae,1d,f9,13,54,00,34,5f,03,02,6b,2e,aa,1d,6f,14,54,00,30,9f,55,00,6b,2e,
> 9c,1d,65,17,e5,02,34,df,b3,01,e9,2f,99,1d

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pascal in the `#dd`, the `dd` is a *decimal* representation of the character, not *hexadecimal*. So `#7c` is not what you think and it won't even compile.

To use a *hexadecimal* representation, use `#$hh`.

Also note that there should be a comma after the `'Caldata9'`, not a plus.

```pascal
RegWriteBinaryValue(
    HKLM64, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FIDTPU\Parameters', 'Caldata9',
    #$7c#$17#$17#$01...);
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. Thanks a lot. You my hero !! I test it.