# Storing the current date to the registry in binary format with Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

Is it possible using Inno Setup to write the current date to a registry key as **binary data**? (if it is a string then that makes it very easy for someone to alter)

In my MFC C++ projects I serialize a [`DATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/date-type) variable using [`WriteProfileBinary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class#writeprofilebinary).

Eventually I need to be able to read this value into a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) variable using .NET C#. I would be using the common program data key to store the value and only if doesn't exist.

---

The [`[Registry]`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm) caters for binary data:

> If `binary` is specified, Setup will create a binary (`REG_BINARY`) value ... If the data type is `binary`, this is a sequence of **hexadecimal bytes** in the form: `"00 ff 12 34"`.

How to we take the **timestamp** and turn it into the required format?

---

I see this question ([Writing binary data to registry using Inno Setup Pascal Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32985231/2287576)) which is useful and also in the Inno Setup forum where they responded to me:

> It's possible, but you'll have to use some `[Code]` and the
> [`RegWriteBinaryValue`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_regwritebinaryvalue.htm) function.

But it is still not clear to me:

1. How to write the current **timestamp** to the registry using this function?
2. How to write it in a binary format such that .NET C# will be able to read it as a `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write the current date to registry as a binary value, you can do something like this:

```pascal
var
  DateStr: string;
begin
  DateStr := GetDateTimeString('yyyy/mm/dd', '-', ':');
  RegWriteBinaryValue(
    HKEY_AUTO, 'Software\My Company\My Program', 'InstallDate', DateStr);
end;
```

It will result in:

```
C:\>reg query "HKCU\Software\My Company\My Program"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\My Company\My Program
    InstallDate    REG_BINARY    323032312D31302D3039
```

---

*You can do even more obfuscation if you like. No matter what you do, user will be able to modify the value with more or less effort.*